# Does IOS Safari support Shadow DOM?

Tags: mobile-safari, web-component, shadow-dom, safari-web-inspector

My application is able to render the Shadow DOM, but the inspector cannot display the shadow root. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on which Shadow DOM you mean—Shadow DOM v0 or Shadow DOM v1.

See http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1 and http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom

No version of Safari supports Shadow DOM v0. But as far as iOS Safari, version 10.2+ support Shadow DOM v1 with the following limitation:

> Certain CSS selectors do not work (`:host > .local-child`) and styling slotted content (`::slotted`) is buggy.

About differences between Shadow DOM v0 and v1, see https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/

---

**2020-07-31 update**: Shadow roots are no longer hidden in Safari Web Inspector — instead they’re now always shown, regardless. See https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/253706/webkit/

---

<sub>In older versions of Safari where Web Inspector does not show shadow roots by default, there’s a button you need to click to show shadow roots; it looks like this:</sub>

[image: WebKit Inspector shadow-dom button]
<sub>And in the Inspector UI, it’s in the toolbar on the right below the tabs. It turns blue when activated:</sub>

[image]

Comment: Shadow DOM V1 for sure. Unfortunately I don't see the shadow root in the inspector. Do I have to turn on some flags or something?

Comment: See the images I just added to the answer

Comment: These brackets are now gone. Any idea where they went?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky Shadow roots are no longer hidden in current Safari Web Inspector — so there’s no longer any need for a button to show them, because they’re now always shown, regardless. See https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/253706/webkit. (I’ve updated the answer to reflect that change.)

Comment: Yep, somehow missed that! Thanks a lot