# How can I see the default stylesheet for iOS Safari browser native elements?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, native

Is there any way to get the default styles for iOS Safari browser?

Specifically, I need the styles for "native" elements, such as `<video>` player UI (which is rendered through HTML and probably styled via CSS styles, just it's not visible in the DOM inspector by default).

Here is few screenshots why I believe it's rendered via html+css and not via real native elements:

children elements insive `<video>` node:
[image: children elements insive <video> node]

a classname visible for the `<div>` elements inside the player UI:
[image: a classname visible for the <div> elements inside the player UI]

These screenshots are from a youtube video, but it's not using any custom player, it's the "native html5" player from Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wow, just after I have made this question I have found the answer!!!

Here is the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270022/does-ios-safari-support-shadow-dom).

The answer is – in the Safari inspector need to Show Shadow DOM nodes with the small `<>` button.